# Ethereum Solidity how to deploy a contract from another contract with constructor function

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, constructor

The old way: constructor function is the same as the contract name:

```
contract CtrtFactory {
  function makeCtrt() {
    address ctrtAddress = new Ctrt(...);
  }
}
contract Ctrt() {
  function Ctrt(..) {}
}
```

-----------------==
But now the new Solidity syntax is saying to use "constructor" as the function name for constructors...:  Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.

```
contract CtrtFactory {
  Ctrt ctrt;
  function makeCtrt() {
    address ctrtAddress = Ctrt.constructor(...);// This gives me ERROR...
  //but I don't know how to fix this.. adding "new" keyword does not help...
  }
}
contract Ctrt() {
  function constructor(..) {}
}
```

-----------------==
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Remix, this compiles:

```
contract CtrtFactory {

    Ctrt ctrt;

    function makeCtrt() {
        Ctrt newCtrt = new Ctrt();
        emit CtrtCreated(newCtrt);
    }

    event CtrtCreated(Ctrt ctrt);
}

contract Ctrt {
    function constructor() {}
}
```

Note that Ctrt's contrstructor is indeed called `constructor`, but we call it using `new Ctrt()`

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I think my Visual Studio Code's linter plugin has problems of not using the latest compiler version. Thanks