# Issue: Defining constructors as functions

Tags: tokens, crowdsale

Why do i ask this? I've been trying to solve this for hours.

Problem version 1:

Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.function TokenERC20(

```
 */
function TokenERC20( 
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
```

Version 2

browser/Test.sol:187:6: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.

```
/* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
 function MyAdvancedToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
) TokenERC20(initialSupply, tokenName, tokenSymbol) public {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Listen to your warning!

```
constructor(
    ...
    ...
```

Its a new solidity thing...the argument that has the same name as the Contract no longer works, you have to use 'constructor'

Comment: I've been doing that for hours now, no kidding, but I just keep getting this  constructor TokenERC20( error lines as this one constructor MyAdvancedToken( : browser/Test.sol:187:21: ParserError: Expected token LParen got 'Identifier'
        constructor MyAdvancedToken(

Answer (score 0):

These both codes, does seem to be annoying. I've been doing exactly that, but it just won't work. It seems alike that there's something that i Should now here.

*/
function TokenERC20( 
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol

function MyAdvancedToken(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol

[image]

browser/Test.sol:45:28: ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'
    Constructors TokenERC20(

[image]

[image]

Comment: the keyword is `constructor`, and you have to remove the contract name (in your case TokenERC20) please check this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45972/ive-got-an-error-while-compiling-use-constructor-instead/45973#45973